# Does preventing exact duplicate titles makes sense here?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, titles

When editing the title of [Multiple FizzBuzz from a file](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/110745/31562), I first wanted to make the title "FizzBuzz from a file" but that exact title [already exists](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/77569/31562) which showed an error message:

[image: A question with that title already exists; please be more specific]

Considering our different definition of duplicates on Code Review (Just because code does the same thing doesn't mean that it is the same code, which doesn't make it a duplicate), does this error message make any sense on Code Review? Should we remove it? **Can we** remove it?

Comment: This is an SE-Wide restriction on titles. Luckily you can circumvent this by adding a few spaces at the end, that will get stripped out after the duplicate check :D

Answer (score 21):

I personally quite like that "warning", it inspires you to create titles that are more imaginative than "FizzBuzz from a file" - how about "IFSFB - Input File Specified FizzBuzz"

Do something different, something that will stand out.

The alternative will be thousands of questions called: "Singly Linked List", or "FizzBuzz", or "Project Euler #13"

If we allow 2, we allow 200 duplicates.

Comment: Also these duplicates then become hard to distinguish without re-reading the question body, and people posting iterations of their code may repeatedly use the same title without modification, making it hard to know the order.